# Abstract class with parameterised constructor of based class called from child class

Tags: c#

As i have one Abstract base class say MyBase.
It have parameterized constructor with string value it have abstract method call.
And I also have One child class say MyChild.
It does not have any constructor only one have public method and i want to call that parameterized  constructor of base class onto child class.

Please give me solution accordingly...

Comment: This question needs some clarification. Please include some code showing your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I really haven't got much of a clue about what you are asking here, so I'll guess:

```
abstract class MyBase
{
    protected MyBase(string foo) { }
}

class Child : MyBase
{
    public Child(string foo)
        : base(foo) 
    { }
}
```

You won't be able to "call" it without it being part of the construction of `Child` as you cannot instantiate abstract classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify constructors in child class than the constructors of parent class will be used. I.e. you can instantiate your Child class as

```
Child child = new Child(initString);
```

the above Child constructor if NOT defined will just propagate (call) parent constructor with the same signature.

Comment: Sorry can't get it. will you please explore it.

Comment: If you base class does not contain parameterless constructor - you can't do that trik.

Comment: @Anton Sizikov: Funny, always thought that this is the way they will behave (never had to try it before) - proven wrong, admit it.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help you without any context, but I'll try.
Maybe you can do something like that:

```
    abstract class MyBase
    {
      protected string _foo;
      protected MyBase(string foo) 
      {
         _foo = foo;
      }
    }

    class Child : MyBase
    {
        public Child()
        :base(string.Empty)
        {}

       public string Foo 
       {
        get 
        {
           return _foo;
         }
         set
         { 
           _foo = value;
          }
    }
}
```

So, as you can't instantiate an abstract class, you can create `var obj = new Child() {Foo = "string"};`
But you can choose this variant only if your `MyBase` just holds the `foo` value.
However, if you can change `Child` you'd better add a constructor to it, as @Adam Houldsworth suggested.

Comment: Thank you, but i dont want to use constructor in my child class is it possible?

Comment: And what about my variant? Does it suitable for you? Or you can't use even a *public Child() :base(string.Empy) {}* ctor?

Comment: I can't use public Child():base(string.empty){}

Comment: Hm, I'm sorry, but it's look like, there is no way to solve the problem :(